# How to handle chained errors?

Tags: python, except

I'm running this code which calls yFinance:

```
try:
    allocation['Price_Data_Cut'], allocation['Price_Current'], allocation['Ticker_CHK'] = zip(*allocation['ETF'].\
        apply(ticker_info, 1, args = (data_cut_datetime,)))
except (SSLError, MaxRetryError, SSLCertVerificationError) as e:
    display('SSL Related Error, prices not fetched')
    pass
```

I'm getting this output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    977         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 978             conn.connect()
    979 

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    361 
--> 362         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    363             sock=conn,

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data)
    383         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 384             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    385 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    499         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501             sock=sock,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040                     self.do_handshake()
   1041             except (OSError, ValueError):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1308                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310         finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    725 
--> 726             retries = retries.increment(
    727                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    438         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 439             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    440 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query2.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v8/finance/chart/SPY?period1=1684735200&period2=1685685600&interval=1d&includePrePost=False&events=div%2Csplits (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-4ca34707d1d0> in <module>
     25 
     26 try:
---> 27     allocation['Price_Data_Cut'], allocation['Price_Current'], allocation['Ticker_CHK'] = zip(*allocation['ETF'].\
     28         apply(ticker_info, 1, args = (data_cut_datetime,)))
     29 except (SSLError, MaxRetryError, SSLCertVerificationError) as e:

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in f(x)
   4183 
   4184             def f(x):
-> 4185                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
   4186 
   4187         else:

<ipython-input-118-4ca34707d1d0> in ticker_info(tickerSymbol, data_cut_datetime)
      8     tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)
      9 #     print(tickerData)
---> 10     prices = tickerData.history(period='1d', start=data_cut_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 
     11             end=(datetime.now() + timedelta(days = 1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
     12 

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/base.py in history(self, period, interval, start, end, prepost, actions, auto_adjust, back_adjust, proxy, rounding, tz, **kwargs)
    150         # Getting data from json
    151         url = "{}/v8/finance/chart/{}".format(self._base_url, self.ticker)
--> 152         data = self.session.get(
    153             url=url,
    154             params=params,

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/Documents/Python/Investing_Analysis/venv_investing_analysis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query2.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v8/finance/chart/SPY?period1=1684735200&period2=1685685600&interval=1d&includePrePost=False&events=div%2Csplits (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Why isn't my `except` statement catching this error?  What should I do to catch this using something more granular than `except Exception` (note except Exception does work)?

I've read the documentation [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and tried changing the order of the errors in the except statement, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Have you imported SSLError `requests.exceptions.SSLError`?

Comment: Are you sure that trace is from the code you show? The trace has `except SSLCertVerificationError as e:` which is not what your code shows.

Answer (score 1):

Python will only catches the final exception type that is raised, not any intermediate exceptions, you have to include `MaxRetryError` in your except, also if you want to handle the `SSLError` when it is wrapped in a `MaxRetryError`, we have to add an additional check.

```
from requests.exceptions import SSLError
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError
from ssl import SSLCertVerificationError

def ticker_info(tickerSymbol, data_cut_datetime):
    # This function should contain your code that might raise the SSLError, MaxRetryError or SSLCertVerificationError

try:
    allocation['Price_Data_Cut'], allocation['Price_Current'], allocation['Ticker_CHK'] = zip(*allocation['ETF'].\
        apply(ticker_info, 1, args = (data_cut_datetime,)))
except (MaxRetryError, SSLCertVerificationError) as e:
    if isinstance(e.reason, SSLError):
        display('SSL Related Error, prices not fetched')
    else:
        display('Max Retry Error, prices not fetched')
    pass
except SSLError as e:
    display('SSL Related Error, prices not fetched')
    pass
```

Comment: I think I was using the wrong SSL error, I needed it from requests, and I was using urllib3.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback message contains this section:

```
     25 
     26 try:
---> 27     allocation['Price_Data_Cut'], allocation['Price_Current'], allocation['Ticker_CHK'] = zip(*allocation['ETF'].\
     28         apply(ticker_info, 1, args = (data_cut_datetime,)))
     29 except SSLCertVerificationError as e:
```

This does not match the code you posted.  Therefore the error is happening in some other part of your code that you did not show us.

Comment: I've updated the error message, but with the some help, I've sorted this out.

Answer (score 0):

As per a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384446/how-to-handle-chained-errors/76384698#comment134692622_76384446) from [@NYC Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6168323/nyc-coder)

I needed to use `from requests.exceptions import SSLError as requests_SSLError`

When I did that `except (requests_SSLError) as e` worked.

Comment: This is a response to a comment, asserting the solution, not a thank you to an answer.